# How can I change CSS height with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to adjust the height of the `.topnav` and its container. How can I do this with javascript `onclick` when the `.icon` is clicked? `myFunction()` should bee triggered.

```html
<div class="topnav" on="myBoi()">
  <img style="width: 380px; height: 300px; position: relative; left: 35%;
            bottom: 40px;" src="mobilfotoğraflar/teknik-soğutma-logo.png" alt="">
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a class="yazı" href="#anasatyfa"></a>
    <a class="yazı" href="#news">News</a>
    <a class="yazı" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a class="yazı" href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: for future reference I recommend you to read about this here. hope it helps: http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/js/js_htmldom_css.asp.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```js
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('id1').style.height= '400px'; }
```

```css
.topnav{background:#eee;}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" on="myBoi()" id="id1">
  <img style="width: 380px; height: 300px; position: relative; left: 35%;
            bottom: 40px;" src="mobilfotoğraflar/teknik-soğutma-logo.png" alt="">
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a class="yazı" href="#anasatyfa"></a>
    <a class="yazı" href="#news">News</a>
    <a class="yazı" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a class="yazı" href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```